# Newsletter is not working after installing mailchimp

Tags: magento2, newsletter, send-mail, mailchimp

After installing Mailchimp in magento 2 newsletter is not working

I saw in system.log and it's give error like

```
[2017-06-30 07:19:29] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Type: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/ Title: Resource Not Found Status: 404 Detail: The requested resource could not be found.
```

so how to solve this error.

Comment: can you please look https://github.com/amro/gibbon/issues/203

Answer (score 0):

I Put Custom Field Setting as Per ScreenShot and I[image] solve my problem.